# Flex/BlazeDS - resultHandler per function call not per RemoteObject?

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

I've followed [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/articles/blazeds_gettingstarted.html) tutorial to get some Flex code to call Java code hosted on a Tomcat server.

This is how my RemoteObject and the Button to call the remote function is declared:

```
<mx:RemoteObject id="productService" destination="productJavaService" result="resultHandler(event)" fault="faultHandler(event)"/>
<mx:Button label="Get all Products" click="productService.getAllProducts()" />
```

These are the definitions of the resultHandler and faultHandler functions:

```
private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    products = event.result as ArrayCollection;
}

private function faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
{
    Alert.show(event.fault.faultString);
}
```

The obvious problem with this for me is that the resultHandler is associated with the RemoteObject as a whole rather than the individual function. If I add a new function such as "getSingleProduct" then obviously a different resultHandler will need to be used.  How do I specify the resultHandler at function level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a `method` property under a `RemoteObject`, in your case, it would be `getAllProducts()`; You can do so like this:

```
<mx:RemoteObject id="Server" destination="ServerDestination" fault="faultHandler(event)">
    <mx:method name="getAllProducts" result="getAllProductsHandler(event)"/>
    <mx:method name="getOneProduct" result="getOneProductHandler(event)"/>
</mx:RemoteObject>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add: in case anyone wants to achieve this with actionscript, you can do this with actionscript by adding a Responder to the AsyncToken returned from the service call:

```
var responder:Responder = new Responder(onGetOneProductResult, onGetOneProductFault);
var token:AsyncToken = Server.getOneProduct();
token.addResponder(responder);

private function onGetOneProductResult(event:ResultEvent):void {
    // event.result is the data you sent back from the server
    var result:Object = event.result;
}

private function onGetOneProductFault(event:FaultEvent):void {
    trace("onGetOneProductFault : "+event.fault.faultString);
}
```